# GPU drivers decreased CPU idle temperature

Tags: drivers, nvidia, overheating, fan, temperature

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my desktop (AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1035T, GeForce GT 440, 8GB DDR3 RAM, Foxconn 2AA9 Motherboard). My CPU temperature was idling at 54-57 degrees celsius and my fan was running ham at 3300 RPM. I tried cleaning the interior and changing the cooling paste to no use. My logs were showing some firmware loading error, which was located to compatibility issues with my GPU. I fixed the problem by installing the Ubuntu nouveau NVidia drivers. Unintentioanlly, this fixed my CPU temperature, which is now running stable between 30-33 degrees celsius and I am getting a smooth 1800 RPM on my fan.

How could installing the GPU drivers lower my CPU temperature?

Comment: It can definitely make a difference, although I don't know why. On an old laptop I have, the proprietary Nvidia drivers run quite a bit cooler than nouveau.  Sadly, the proprietary drivers are not supported on the new kernels....

Comment: I'm no expert but I think after installing the GPU driver your system began to utilize your GPU for graphical work. Which in turn decreased the pressure on CPU; thus decreasing it's temperature.